# nsarray with a lot of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm new. Help please, how to make it short:

```
effects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Back1.jpg", @"Back2.jpg", @"Back3.jpg", @"Back4.jpg", @"Back5.jpg", @"Back6.jpg", @"Back7.jpg", @"Back8.jpg",@"Back9.jpg",nil];
```

thnaks. I want something like @"back%i.jpg", int++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with for loops?

```
int whatever = 100;
NSMutableArray * effectsTmp = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < whatever; i++) {
     [effects addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Back%i.jpg", i]];
}
NSArray * effects = effectsTmp;
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you want something like:

```
NSMutableArray * effects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if(effects)
{
   for( NSInteger index = 0; index < 10; index++)
   {
      [effects addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Back%i.jpg", index];
   }
}
```

Comment: Ugh, *non-egyptian* curly braces?  I know this is April fools day, but seriously, man? ;)

Comment: i just wan to creat a srollView with these images

Comment: that sounds like a different question than what you asked above, Mary.

Comment: Isn't the `if(effects)` check a little paranoid?

Comment: Right... 99.9% of the time, an alloc/init will succeed, but one tends to get dinged at code review time (or job interview time) if one doesn't do enough error checking in their code.

Comment: I'm with @GabrielePetronella.  Why trap for errors you can do nothing about?  If alloc is failing, you're about to crash and burn.  Might as well enjoy your last few milliseconds of life.  (but +1 on the good answer anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big an array you need, you can take advantage of NSArray's very simple subclassing. You only need to override two methods, `count` and `objectAtIndex:`.

```
@interface StringArray : NSArray
@end

@implementation StringArray

-(NSUInteger)count {
    return 9;
}

-(id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Back%ld.jpg", (long)(index +1)];
}

@end
```

To use it, simply instantiate it:

```
NSArray *stringArray = [[StringArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Array: %@", stringArray);
```

This solution uses a few extra lines of code compared to building the array through a for loop, but on the upside, it should use less memory for large arrays.

An array like this can be useful in some situations as the model object for an array controller.

I don't know how it would hold up to a code review, some might find that the hard-coded size and format string could need some work.